# WPF Listbox: Not showing image inside button in each element

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I am developing a large application in WPF and C# since 2011 (.NET Framework 4.0). On Windows 7 all worked fine. Now, on Windows 10 there are some new problems.
One of them is: A Listbox containing a text label and a delete button with an image (red cross) inside. The orientation of the items is horizontal, so that several items can be displayed in one row. If the overriding grid is too small for displaying all items in one row the next items are wrapped into the next row.
Now, on some computers (not all) in production (not able to reconstruct this on my development computer) WPF shows the red cross inside the button only in the first and sometimes in the second item of a row, the rest of the items in the row contain blank buttons.

[See this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imUKh.jpg)

(I had to hide the text fields since they contain names of real persons)

The XAML of ItemTemplate and ItemsPanel:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ParticipantItemTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding FullName}"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding PersonType}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Template="{DynamicResource ButtonTemplate}" Click="ParticipantDeleteButton_Click">
                <Image Height="Auto" Source="_media/_ico/close.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
            </Button>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ParticipantsItemsPanelTemplate">
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>

            <ListBox x:Name="ParticipantList" ItemsSource="{Binding ActivePatients}"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ParticipantItemTemplate}" ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ParticipantsItemsPanelTemplate}" Margin="0 2 0 2" MouseDoubleClick="ParticipantList_MouseDoubleClick"/>
```

The XAML of the listbox:

```
            <ListBox x:Name="ParticipantList" ItemsSource="{Binding ActivePatients}"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ParticipantItemTemplate}" ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ParticipantsItemsPanelTemplate}" Margin="0 2 0 2" MouseDoubleClick="ParticipantList_MouseDoubleClick"/>
```

XAML of ButtonTemplate:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" Style="{DynamicResource dialogBorder}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Border.RenderTransform>
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFD7E4F2" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <Border.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ComponentBorderColorGradient}" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ComponentBorderColor}" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.BorderBrush>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid x:Name="grid">
            <ContentPresenter />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I have been searching for this problem since a long time, but not found anything helpful.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide the ```ButtonTemplate``` referenced here:
```<Button Grid.Column="1" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Template="{DynamicResource ButtonTemplate}" Click="ParticipantDeleteButton_Click">```